# no puedo ejecutar mi programa ya que en while me marca error

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    MisGastos gastosVacaciones = new MisGastos();
    double leerGastos =0.0;

    System.out.print("Introduzca un gasto generado en el viaje o -1 para terminar:"); {
    leerGastos =entrada.nextDouble();
    while(leerGastos);
```

aqui me dice que esta mal en while por lo cual me marca error

Comment: Hola! Te recuero que While es un bucle, que si se cumple una condicion, ejecuta cierto codigo. Por ejemplo:

Comment: para que usas el while? te manda error por que no le estas pasando una condicion de inicio y fin ni algo que se repita

Comment: Boolean valor = true;
While (valor){
//ejecuta codigo,
}

Answer (score 1):

Vos lo que deberia de poner en tu codigo seria algo asi:

```
int leerGastos = 0;
System.out.print("Introduzca un gasto generado en el viaje o -1 para terminar:");
leerGastos =entrada.nextInt();
while(leerGastos != -1){
   System.out.println("su gasto fue: " + leerGastos);
   System.out.println("Introduzca un gasto generado en el viaje o -1 para terminar:");
   leerGastos =entrada.nextInt();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

el error se produce ya que en el bucle `while` no le estas pasando una condición, lo correcto seria poner esto:

```
int x = 1;

while(leerGastos == x){
    //pasa algo
}
```

De pronto te confundiste con la variable `boolean`, que de forma predeterminada ya condiciona el bucle, no haciendo necesario el `== true` o `== false`, un ejemplo:

```
boolean leerGastos = false;

while(leerGastos){
    //no pasa nada
}
```